# How to fix misaligned floating desk frame?

Tags: wood, mounting, carpentry, furniture

I am a new "DIY-er" and have recently taken upon myself the project of building a floating desk with the intent of expanding it later on (i.e., adding shelves, mounting monitor racks, etc.) but was building the frame and noticed a huge problem.

The frame itself is not aligned with the ends and I am not sure how to go about it.
The reason I know this is because I built most of the frame and went to put the other 2x4 stud on it and it did not align **at all**. Please see the attached link which will take you to a drive with 5 pictures of the project. I used a Kreg Pocket Jig (Model 320) to insert pocket screws and connect the joints of the wood. The first picture shows the misalignment with the wood and it is consistently like that.

**My question is:** How can I easily make the frame aligned so that the frame can be mounted on the wall without having to spend excessively money? Keep in mind I went to Home Depot to have the wood cut and have minimal tools and I do not have a lot of space.

Thank you everyone for your help in advance as I make progress with this project! Have a great day!

[image: Misaligned Floating Desk Frame Visual]
[image: Floating Desk Frame Right Side]
[image: Floating Desk Frame Center]
[image: Floating Desk Frame Left Side]
[image: Floating Desk Frame Built]

Comment: Those pictures are extremely small and its nearly impossible to make out what you're talking about. Consider uploading some better photos.

Comment: I can't see much in your tiny pictures, either, but it's basically a matter of making accurate cuts on lumber that's straight to get things to line up. Neither are particularly guaranteed with Homely Despot, though you might be able to improve things by keeping track of which side was where when cutting when assembly time comes, so that you're not amplifying errors by swapping things around.

Comment: When you say "floating" is this desk intended to be supported only at the wall?

Comment: You might want to search for past answers re floating desks. That trick almost never works; support at the free corner(s) is required.

Comment: Wood, especially  cheap construction grade "white wood", isn't straight unless you make it straight. It doesn't generally stay straight unless there are forces holding it there.

Comment: There's a lot less labor and money involved if you just glue together 2 pieces of plywood to make such a desk. A 4 ft square piece gives you up to a 2 ft by 4 ft desk surface. You might ask another question about how you intend to mount this to the wall.

Comment: @Huesmann I was intending to build the desk supported by 2 walls in the corner. For the free corner, I would use a drawer that fits underneath to prevent that from being a problem.

Comment: @matt. Thanks for letting me know. I originally used the small thumbnail on imgur to format it but now they are bigger. If you see in the first picture, when the 2x4 is on "top", the horizontal beams go over that part of the frame if that makes sense, and if I move it to adjust it, another section becomes visible.

Comment: @keshlam I was actually going to use a drawer that was the same size as the space underneath the desk to fulfill that problem. I've seen other people in the past who had a problem with support by 2 walls so I figured that would my best bet.

Comment: @popham I was also going to mount it to the wall via 3" deck screws that would break through the drywall and into the studs. I was thinking about using wood glue but I watched a few videos and they all used a pocket jig and screws which I figured would be better.

Comment: I don't think that pocket screws fastening to the wall make any sense. You should be screwing through the face of that back 2x4. Your wood glue comment has me baffled, so maybe I'm not understanding something. You already seem to have a handle on the outside corner's sagging. A threaded rod up to a ceiling joist or a chain to a wall stud can be aesthetically interesting alternatives to a leg.

Comment: By drawer you mean drawer pedestal/short filing cabinet? That would work. Of course if you put one on both ends it no longer has to float... Agreed, pocket screws to the wall makes little sense. Pocket screws are a joinery technique, not a mounting technique.

Comment: Hey @keshlam I was going to use pocket screws to join the vertical and horizontal beams together to make the frame, and then I was going to use 3" deck screws to mount it to the wall with a short filing cabinet on the free corner for additional support, as I saw in another post that problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You mean that the tips of the framing aren't in a straight line? Attach the first one, and then work your way down the line. Force the misaligned pieces into alignment. It should be pretty easy because the beam at the other end is very flexible in torsion. Pushing the joists with that 2 ft of leverage, the beam at the other end will twist (or maybe untwist).

Rather than twisting it by hand and trying to fasten things simultaneously, consider clamping a scrap piece of wood across the joint to immobilize things so you can focus elsewhere as you install your fasteners. Be sure to keep the joint tight since you're using pocket screws, though. And alternatively, you can temporarily screw this scrap wood in place instead of clamping if you don't mind the scars (you can position the scars so that they bury between the desk surface and the framing).

Comment: When you say "bull" them around, can you clarify? Right now I have all of it screwed together except the last piece (which is the problem - see the last picture) and so I am not sure how to bull it around.

Comment: @Meowman1012, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are assuming that the 2x4 that is not aligned is the same length.

Or, you are expecting there to be no twist or bow in the 2x4s which are framing members and not meant to be used for close tolerance furniture projects.

Comment: Hey @RMDman, it is the same approximate length. If you look at the first picture, you see that when I say it is not aligned, I mean the piece of wood that would go "on top" to complete the frame does not align with all of the support beams that would build the frame. I tried moving it around to get them to adjust, but a piece of "beam" would always be visible if that makes sense.

Comment: @ Meowman1012,  The bigger pics help, but as said in my answer and as popham has suggested, you will need to move the pieces into position.  Again framing wood is not meant for furniture construction. You will have to work with the twists and bows and forget the perfect alignment. Otherwise you need to either purchase better grade wood that has been milled straight or plane the studs flat and straight yourself.

Comment: Do you think it is okay to redrill into the longer supports with compromising the structural integrity too much? In order to realign it, I would have to redrill the pocket screws, and so the pocket hole would be much bigger if that makes sense.

Comment: Pocket screws are not the proper method of anchoring framing members.  With respect for your "out of the box" thinking, I believe you are using the wrong methods and materials for what you are trying to accomplish.